# Wrong Component (in seperate JPanel class) gets focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, components, setfocus

I'm working on an application with the following structure:

1. **FrmMain** (which houses the panel I want to add my "layout" panel to)
2. **PnlNewCase** (the "layout" panel which is set to receive zone specific panels)
3. **PnlNewCaseNotes** (one of the panels which is added to PnlNewCase)
4. **PnlNewPartsSelection** (*the bane of my existence*)

My idea was to put into focus a specific JTextField (tfNom) whenever I create a new page in PnlNewPartsSelection whenever it is instantiated but whenever I try to do that, the focus is set to another JTextField altogether (tfAddressDetails).

[What I want in focus (in blue) vs what gets focus (in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YxT3.jpg)

I've tried debugging the whole thing and Haven't been able to pinpoint what needs to be done. I've also tried to reproduce the issue using a simpler code but in that case it works. The only notable difference between the two is that the simplified code is only comprised of a JFrame and a JPanel while the more complex code contains: JFrame -> JTabbedPane -> Jpanel -> Jpanel so I wonder if this isn't linked to the JTabedPane to JPanel or JPanel to JPanel interaction somehow.

Here's the rundown of the methods I'm using which I hope can help someone figure out what's going on.

**JFrame FrMain:**

```
private void btnNewRepActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    tabs.addTab("R" + tabNo++, p);
    tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabNo);
}
```

**JPanel PnlNewCase:**

```
public PnlNewCase(boolean isNewRep) {
    initComponents();
    checkRepStatus(isNewRep);
}


private void checkRepStatus(boolean isNewRep) {
    if (isNewRep) {
        btnNewNote.setVisible(false);
        PnlNewCaseNotes p1 = new PnlNewCaseNotes();
        pnlNotes.add(p1);
        PnlNewPartsSelection p2 = new PnlNewPartsSelection();      
        JTextField t = p2.getTfNom();
        pnlPartsCustomer.add(p2);
        t.requestFocusInWindow();
        validate();
    }
}
```

**JPanel PnlNewCaseNotes:**

```
public PnlNewCaseNotes() {
    initComponents();
}
```

**JPanel PnlNewPartsSelection:**

```
public PnlNewPartsSelection() {
    initComponents();
}

/* A bunch of method calls to add place holders */

public JTextField getTfNom() {
    return tfNom;
}
```

I can also post the code for each class if need be (I just think that this should be sufficient).

Looking forward to your comments :)

Comment: It is unlikely that `PnlNewCase` is has physical on the screen when you call `t.requestFocusInWindow()`, which makes the call mute.  You need to realise `PnlNewCase` on the UI first, then redirect control. Maybe after you call `add` (and `revalidate`/`repaint`), call `requestFocusInWindow` ... you may find you need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to make it work though

Answer (score 2):

Take a step back and walk through your code.  Let's assume you're doing something like

```
add(new PnlNewCase(true));
```

If you walk through the code you will find it calls:

- `PnlNewCase` constructor (assigns default values to instance fields)

  - `initComponents`

    - `checkRepStatus`. At this point you start building your code and call `t.requestFocusInWindow`
- Calls `add` passing the new instance of `PnlNewCase` to the container

And here in lies the core problem.  When you call `t.requestFocusInWindow`, neither the component itself or the container it's attached to have been added to the UI, so it's impossible for the field to be given focus.

Instead, add the component to the UI and then request focus to the field.  Because of the way that the frameworks, you might find you also need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to make the focus work

Maybe doing something like...

```
    public class PnlNewCase extends JPanel {

        private PnlNewPartsSelection p2;

        public PnlNewCase(boolean isNewRep) {
            //...
        }

        private void checkRepStatus(boolean isNewRep) {
            if (isNewRep) {
                //...
                p2 = new PnlNewPartsSelection();
                //...
                //t.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }

        public void focusPrimaryField() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    p2.getTfNom().requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Then you can simply do something like...

```
PnlNewCase newCase = new PnlNewCase(true);
add(newCase);
revalidate();
repaint();
newCase.focusPrimaryField()
```

As a general idea.

You may also like to have a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) to get a better understanding and maybe some more ideas

Comment: Thanks for taking the time answer my question  ! You've helped me understand what is the issue and I thank you for that. On the other hand I'm having trouble understanding how the last fragment of code would come into play. Especially the newCase.focusPrimaryField() call.

From What I've understood, you added the the focusPrimaryField() method to the PnlNewCase class but I don't get where the last fragment should be.

FrmMain ?

Comment: The idea is to delay the request focus until a time you can better guarantee that the ui is established on the screen

Comment: The important part here is the UI established (the components are added and, if possible, realised on the screen).  You could add the call to `focusPrimaryField` before `setVisible` and it "might" work, but it might be safer to add it after the `setVisible` call if possible

Comment: since my structure is tab creation, main panel append, context panel append, I've tried adding the call tofocusPrimaryField(which is found in PnlNewCase)at the end of the tab creation process hopping that that would correspond to coming back to the root call but it hasn't worked. I might be having trouble understanding exactly what you are suggesting I do with what you posted.
Also, I've turned to some of my older more experienced peers who have suggested I use a custom traversal policy which I've tried but it doesn't take.